# Flixel error "FlxPreloader was not found."

Tags: flash, flixel

When I run my Flixel code in Flash develop it throws this error:

> col: 33 Error: The definition of base class FlxPreloader was not found.

my code:

```
package  
{
    import org.flixel.FlxPreloader;
    public class Preloader extends FlxPreloader
    {

        public function Preloader() 
        {
        className = "Jumper";
        super();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FlxPreloader` is in the package `org.flixel.system.FlxPreloader`.

Change your import statement to look like this:

`import org.flixel.system.FlxPreloader;`